# Simple Android Method Crashing..why?

Tags: java, android

I'm a new programmer, and I only know the basics of Java/Android programming. I'm trying to make a basic app to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius. I coded the method to do it, hooked it up to a button, and my app crashes. I could not seem to find the error and/or an alternative way of doing it. I was wondering if anyone knew what caused the crash and if they can tell me how to avoid it in the future. This would benefit me as well as beginner Java programmers.

Here is my Java Code:

```
    public void appControl (View view){

    EditText giveFarenheit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.farenheit_int);
    String oldFarenheitString = giveFarenheit.getText().toString();
    int oldFarenheit=Integer.parseInt(oldFarenheitString);
    int step1 = oldFarenheit - 32;
    int newCelcius = step1*5/9;
    EditText giveCelcius = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.celcius_int);
        giveCelcius.setHint(oldFarenheit);

}
```

Here is the log with the crash:

```
08-28 22:07:55.384  14825-14825/com.paulrotman.tempconverterfree E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.paulrotman.tempconverterfree, PID: 14825
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4247)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:20916)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5972)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4242)
```

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5191)

Comment: full stacktrace. this is only the beginning.

Comment: can you also please provide more code? maybe usages of appControl?, also full stacktrace as mentioned before.

Comment: Follow and do [this](http://allandroidexamples.blogspot.com/2012/12/sum-of-two-number-using-edittext-and.html) example. It is somewhat similar to your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Your this line is causing error, i guess:

```
giveCelcius.setHint(oldFarenheit);
```

Its simply because you are giving integer as an argument instead of `CharacterSequence[]` (I guess); So just add `+""` to make it String, and your code should work.

...

```
giveCelcius.setHint(oldFarenheit+"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this.

> (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.farenheit_int);

```
public void appControl (View view){
   EditText giveFarenheit = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.farenheit_int);
   String oldFarenheitString = giveFarenheit.getText().toString();
   int oldFarenheit=Integer.parseInt(oldFarenheitString);
   int step1 = oldFarenheit - 32;
   int newCelcius = step1*5/9;
   EditText giveCelcius = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.celcius_int);
   giveCelcius.setHint(String.ValueOf(oldFarenheit));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

don't initialize EditText giveFarenheit inside a method.
instead of doing this way

do like this
EditText giveFarenheit; above the method

giveFarenheit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.farenheit_int);
it may be resolve the problem

see the bellow link
[Android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530535/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-of-the-activit)

Comment: Unfortunately, after I tried that, the app just simply crashed when I ran it instead of the layout showing up and crashing after I pushed the button