# Why does my activity crash when I try to get a number?

Tags: java, android

I have an activity, called `AddItem`, which contains a couple fields that the user fills out and I am now trying to pass them to another activity. I was able to get the first two fields by doing this:

```
String messageText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName)).getText().toString();
String discriptionText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
```

The above code worked fun, but then I tried to get another value which I then cast to a double like so:

```
double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude)).getText().toString());
```

It's kind of long and complicated but I'm basically doing the same thing with the exception of parsing the String and converting it to a double value. I determined that this is the problem code because when I comment it out the rest of the app runs fine.

Here is my Activity:

```
public class AddItem extends AppCompatActivity {

  EditText inputedTask, inputedDescription, inputedLatitude;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);
    inputedTask = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName);
    inputedDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.description);
    inputedLatitude = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude);
  }

  public void onSaveItemButton(View view) {
    String messageText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputName)).getText().toString();
    String discriptionText = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.description)).getText().toString();
    double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude)).getText().toString());

    if (messageText.equals(""));
    else {
      Intent intent = new Intent();
      intent.putExtra(Intent_Constant.INTENT_MESSAGE_FIELD, messageText);
      setResult(Intent_Constant.INTENT_RESULT_CODE, intent);
      finish();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your EditText contains a properly formatted Double?

Comment: Perhaps tell us the error you're receiving?

Comment: @Selvin I'm sorry what does that mean?

Comment: Check the logcat when the app crash and you will see exactly in what line the app crash. Also you can copy the exception and post here.

Comment: @ChrisGong That's part of the problem the error is very vague it just says `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick` and I've isolated it to this line.

Comment: @YayoArellano I've posted the error message.

Comment: Maybe no `onSaveItemButton()` method in your code?

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך There is and if it wasn't there then the other two would't be working.

Comment: Maybe making a public one: `public void onSaveItemButton(View view)`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make a public method for the onClick, from the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html):

> Within the Activity that hosts this layout, the following method
>   handles the click event:
>
> ```
> /** Called when the user touches the button */ 
> public void sendMessage(View view) {
>   // Do something in response to button click 
> }
> ```
>
> The method you declare in the [android:onClick](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#onClick) attribute must have a
>   signature exactly as shown above. Specifically, the method must:
>
> - Be public
> - Return void
> - Define a View as its only parameter (this will
>     be the View that was clicked)

So you ***need*** to change the method to **public**:

```
public void onSaveItemButton(View view) {
  ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**
As the error log says:

> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698) 
>                      **Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""**
>                         at java.lang.StringToReal.invalidReal(StringToReal.java:63)
>                         at java.lang.StringToReal.parseDouble(StringToReal.java:267)
>                         at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:301)
>                         at cs4720.cs.virginia.edu.duysalahandroidminiproject02.AddItem.onSaveItemButton(AddItem.java:33)

You need to catch for empty string in the following code:

```
double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude)).getText().toString());
```

so, check it first:

```
String val = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.Latitude)).getText().toString();
if(!val.equals("") {
  double Latitude = Double.parseDouble(val);
}
```

Comment: I've posted the updated error message. Although it looks the same as the previous one.

Comment: You need to catch an empty string, as the error says: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""`. So everytime you have an empty string, skip the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

You are calling **onSaveItemButton** method from a view that is not initialized. You must initialize **btnChangeDate** in the **onCreate** from the activity.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14530587/3479489)

Comment: Where are you seeing `onSaveItemButton` in this question?

Comment: So are you saying that I can fix the problem just by doing something like `Latitude= (EditText) findViewById (R.id.Latitude)` in my `onCreate` method? If that's required then why did I not need to do the same for the other two fields? Just curious.

Comment: @AnixPasBesoin In the XML portion. It's the method called when you hit the button.