# onClick Submit is crashes android

Tags: java, android

I need to create a login page with register activity.
At the register activity I have `Submit` where I need to receive *user name, password and password verification.*

Every time I press the "Submit" button, the app crushes.

Any ideas why?

```
public class RegActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText rName;
    EditText rPassword;
    EditText sPassword;
    String name;
    String pass;
    String secPass;
    SharedPreferences prefs;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);
        rName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regName);
        rPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPass);
        sPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.regPass2);
        name = ((EditText)rName).getText().toString();
        pass = ((EditText)rPassword).getText().toString();
        secPass = ((EditText)sPassword).getText().toString();
    }

    public void submit(View v){
        if (rPassword.getText().equals(sPassword.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Passwords don't match!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rName.setText("");
            rPassword.setText("");
            sPassword.setText("");
        }
        else {
            User nUser = new User (name, pass);
            saveUser(nUser);
            prefs = getSharedPreferences("usersData", MODE_PRIVATE);
            Intent i = new Intent(RegActivity.this, UserActivity.class).putExtra("userName", nUser.getName().toString());
        }
    }
```

The error I receive:
 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: com.example.baseproject, PID: 20125 java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: can you please show your logs

Comment: I this is what's really matters:
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.baseproject, PID: 20125
                  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

Comment: @Itay plesae attach your layout file laso

Comment: Not sure why you put "Intent intent = getIntent();" at the very beginning?
You could also use an onClickListener, just an advice for better codingThat would be great if you could share your logs

Comment: @AndriiAbramov it won't let me post the XML format layout :(

Comment: Post your error also

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530535/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-of-the-activit)

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
if (rPassword.getText().toString().equals(sPassword.getText().toString())) {
```

getText() : return charSequence and you are comparing charSequence with String so replace it. it should work.

But I am not getting why you are checking rPassword with rPassword both are same.

Comment: He is comparing with sPassword ;)

Comment: I'm actually checking if rPassword is equals to sPassword in order to have a password verification

Comment: When I type un-match passwords, the app crushes, when I type match passwords it recognize it as un-match passwords

Comment: You print a post toast with "unmatch" if sPassword is equal to rPassword.

Answer (score 0):

there might be a mistake in the xml..
try this

```
<Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:onClick="submit"
 />
```

you can try to remove all the code in the method and check it if this works.