# How to check SQLite database if user has already existed?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am a new at Android programming. I have a SQLite database with emails and passwords, and I want to check if user has already existed when new user creates new account. Can anyone help me ?
This is my method which checking if user exist.

```
            usersAcc.setEmailUser(e);
            usersAcc.setPasswordUser(a);
            String query = "SELECT email FROM Emails WHERE email='"+ usersAcc.getEmailUser() +"';";
            Cursor cursor = helper.sqlite.rawQuery(query, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if(cursor.moveToNext()){
                helper.intput(usersAcc);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
                toast.show();
            }else{
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
                toast.show();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using move of cursor correctly, because after moving to first you make a move to next which does not exist, use this:

```
usersAcc.setEmailUser(e);
usersAcc.setPasswordUser(a);
String query = "SELECT email FROM Emails WHERE email='"+ usersAcc.getEmailUser() +"';";
Cursor cursor = helper.sqlite.rawQuery(query, null);

if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
    helper.intput(usersAcc);
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
    toast.show();
}else{
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
    toast.show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use  [**`if(cursor.moveToNext())`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst())---> This method will return false if the cursor is already past the last entry in the result set.

You should use [**`if(cursorOBJECT.moveToFirst())`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#moveToFirst()).

> Move the cursor to the first row.This method will return false if the
>   cursor is empty.

```
Cursor cursor=helper.sqlite.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user WHERE email ='"+ usersAcc.getEmailUser()+"'", null);
if(cursor.moveToFirst())
{
 helper.intput(usersAcc);
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "OK!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
                toast.show();
}
else
{
 Toast toast = Toast.makeText(RegistrationForm.this, "Fail!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0,0);
                toast.show();
}
```

FYI

```
"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity"
```

Signals that a method has been invoked at an illegal or inappropriate time. In other words, the Java environment or Java application is not in an appropriate state for the requested operation.

Comment: When I start my program and try to  input some data to my database, I catch "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity" but when I do not try to check if user exist, the data add successfully

Comment: @Papav Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530535/android-java-lang-illegalstateexception-could-not-execute-method-of-the-activit

Comment: @Papav Uninstall old app and run once again. If problem coming then please DEBUG your application. Add break-point.

Comment: @Papav  `usersAcc.setEmailUser(e);
            usersAcc.setPasswordUser(a);` check values of `a` .

Comment: Ok I will try. Thanks!

Comment: @Papav Solved this yet?